# Use jQuery to Get Previous Immediate li Item in Nested List

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list

[image: get previous li item in nested list]

If I have a nested list and I want to use jQuery or Javascript to get the previous item in the list from the selector. The catch is, this is a nested list so the previous item might be a nested list item from another ol.

Here's what I mean.

- Previous to jQuery `#('#topic_17')` would be Django `#('#topic_2')`
- Previous to Django `#('#topic_2')` would be Bootstrap 4 `#('#topic_11')`
- Previous to Bootstrap 4 `#('#topic_11')` would be Frameworks `#('#topic_3')`
- Previous to Frameworks `#('#topic_3')` would be CSS `#('#topic_5')`
- Previous to CSS `#('#topic_5')` would be HTML `#('#topic_1')`
- Previous to HTML `#('#topic_1')` would be Web Development `#('#topic_13')`
- Previous to Web Development `#('#topic_13')` would be nothing.

I see a few possible ways but really want a smarter, more generalized way of selecting if it's possible. Previous element situations I can think of:

1. The previous li is not nested so it's just `$(selector).prev('li')`
2. The previous li is nested so get the last li with `$(selector).prev('li').find('li').last()`
3. The previous li is a parent so `$(selector).closest('ol').parent()`
4. There is no previous li because it's the top item in the list.

Any generalized, easy way to accomplish this?

#### HTML Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ol class="list-group list-group-root sortable">

            <li id="topic_13">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Web Development</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ol>
                    
                    <li id="topic_1">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <span>HTML</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li id="topic_5">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <span>CSS</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <ol>

                            <li id="topic_3">
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Frameworks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <ol>

                                    <li id="topic_11">
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <span>Bootstrap 4</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                </ol>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>


            <li id="topic_2">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Django</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            <li id="topic_17">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>jQuery</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ol>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `.slice` to filter the matched elements returned by jQuery. See this example:

```js
// Get all li elements
const elements = jQuery("li");

// select the element we need
const el = jQuery("#topic_11");

// get index of the element
const idx = elements.index(el);

// get previous by slicing from the previous index (-1)
const prevElement = elements.slice(idx - 1, idx);

if (prevElement.length == 0)
  console.log("No Previous Element");

if (prevElement.length > 0)
  console.log(prevElement[0], prevElement.attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="list-group list-group-root sortable">

  <li id="topic_13">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>Web Development</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ol>

      <li id="topic_1">
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>HTML</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li id="topic_5">
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>CSS</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ol>

          <li id="topic_3">
            <div>
              <div>
                <span>Frameworks</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <ol>

              <li id="topic_11">
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <span>Bootstrap 4</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>

            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>


  <li id="topic_2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>Django</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li id="topic_17">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>jQuery</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: very clean solution! Thanks for the help. I was racking my tiny brain over this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a collection of *all* spans on the page. When a span is clicked, find the index of that span in the collection, then reference that `index - 1` in the collection to get to the previous one:

```js
const spans = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')];

spans.forEach((span, i) => {
  span.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(spans[i - 1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<ol class="list-group list-group-root sortable">

  <li id="topic_13">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>Web Development</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ol>

      <li id="topic_1">
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>HTML</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li id="topic_5">
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>CSS</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ol>

          <li id="topic_3">
            <div>
              <div>
                <span>Frameworks</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <ol>

              <li id="topic_11">
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <span>Bootstrap 4</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>

            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>


  <li id="topic_2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>Django</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li id="topic_17">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>jQuery</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

`spans[i - 1]` gives you the `<span>`, of course. If you want to navigate to its containing `<li>`, check if the span exists, and if it does, do `.closest('li')`.